# CONVERT datetime not working in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, reportbuilder

I have a stored procedure that I am using in Report Builder and in the query I have two columns that are dates where I have set them up as;
CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(CHAR(8), EZ.ACDT), 101) as 'ACCOUNTING DATE',
CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(CHAR(8), EZ.TRDT), 101) AS'TRANSACTION DATE'

and the stored procedure executes without errors, however, when I run the report in design mode in Report Builder, I get the following error message;

"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

I have already searched other questions on SOF and tried to implement what was advised as having worked in other cases, but none have worked for me.

What is unusual is that I have used this same set up of CONVERT on other stored procedures that I have built using the same table and columns that have worked fine, but for some reason, I am not getting this error message;

"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RPT_CAS300_REPORT]
(
--The below variables are used as parameters to search in Report Builder.  The date variables are range dates
@DIVISION NVARCHAR(50)
,@FROMACCDATE date
,@TOACCDATE date
,@FROMTRANSDATE date
,@TOTRANSDATE date
,@ERRORCODE NVARCHAR(50)

)

AS

BEGIN


select distinct
EZ.DIVI AS 'DIVISION',
EZ.ANBR AS 'ACCOUNT NUMBER',
EZ.SENO AS 'SEQ NO',
EZ.EVEN AS 'EVENT',
CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(CHAR(8), EZ.ACDT), 101) as 'ACCOUNTING DATE',
CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(CHAR(8), EZ.TRDT), 101) AS'TRANSACTION DATE',
EZ.ACTY AS 'ACCOUNT TYPE',
EZ.ITNO AS 'ITEM NUMBER',
MM.ITDS AS 'STYLE',
MM.BUAR AS 'BRAND',
MM.ITGR AS 'CLASS',
EZ.ACQT AS 'QUANTITY',
EZ.ACAM AS 'RECORDED AMOUNT',
EZ.AIT1 AS 'DIM 1: GL',
EA.TX40 AS 'GL DESCRIPTION',
EZ.AIT2 AS 'DIM 2: COST CENTRE',
EZ.AIT3 AS 'DIM 3: BRAND',
EZ.AIT4 AS 'DIM 4: CHANNEL',
EZ.AIT5 AS 'DIM 5: WAREHOUSE',
EZ.AIT6 AS 'DIM 6: ORDER',
EZ.AIT7 AS 'DIM 7: ACCOUNTING RULE',
EZ.RGDT AS 'END DATE',
EZ.ERCD AS 'ERROR CODE'
from CINACC EZ
left join MITMAS MM on MM.CONO = EZ.CONO
    and MM.ITNO = EZ.ITNO
    and EZ.deleted = 'N'
left join FCHACC EA on EA.CONO = EZ.CONO
    and EA.AITM = EZ.AIT1
    and EA.deleted = 'N'
where EZ.CONO = '100'
    AND (EZ.DIVI IN ( SELECT Value FROM dbo.FnSplit( @DIVISION,',') ) OR @DIVISION IS NULL ) 
    AND (EZ.ERCD IN ( SELECT Value FROM dbo.FnSplit( @ERRORCODE,',') ) OR @ERRORCODE IS NULL ) 
    AND CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(CHAR(8), EZ.ACDT), 101) BETWEEN @FROMACCDATE AND @TOACCDATE
    AND CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(CHAR(8), EZ.TRDT), 101) BETWEEN @FROMTRANSDATE AND @TOTRANSDATE
    AND EZ.deleted = 'N'


END
```

Comment: Why are you converting your columns to a `datetime` in the first place? Surely they are already a strongly typed data and time value, no? If not, then why not fix your design?

Comment: Also, style `101` is `MM/dd/yyyy` but you're truncating your values to 8 characters; I'm surprised that query worked at all

Comment: If your upper boundary `@TOACCDATE` is intended to be inclusive, it is far more efficient to simply add 1 day to this date and use it as an exclusive upper boundary.  Casting a column to a different datatype in a WHERE clause will prevent the use of any useful indexes containing that column.

Comment: @Larnu the data type for the date column is INT it is the way the database has been set up.  It has been escalated to the software development as an IMPROVEMENT but a known issue by many people who work with this ERP software have raised the same issue and request for improvement many times before me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Caveat:** This answer *assumes* that your date (and time) columns are a strongly typed date and time data type, because *why wouldn't they be?* If this is not true, the problem is your design; stop storing date (and time) data in a `varchar`. Fix the design, fix the problem.

---

Let's look at one of your expressions:

```sql
CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(CHAR(8), EZ.ACDT), 101) BETWEEN @FROMACCDATE AND @TOACCDATE
```

So, what does this do? Firstly, let's start at `CONVERT(CHAR(8), EZ.ACDT)`, which converts the value of `EZ.ACDT` (which remember we are assuming is astrongly typed date and time data type) and converting it to a `char(8)`. There's no style noted, so SQL Server is free to use it's default options, and would vary by language.

For myself (who is English), this means that the value for `GETDATE()` returned would be `'Sep  2 2'`; a completely nonsense value. If I were American I would get the same value. Were I French or Japanese I would get the values `'sept  2 '` and `'09  2 20'` respectively. Do you see a problem here? I hope so.

Next we have `CONVERT(datetime,{prior expression}, 101)`. The style number `101` is for `MM/dd/yyyy`. Firstly this is **10** characters, and we've already truncated the value to `8`; a problem. Next, *none* of these prior values look anything like that format. For `BRITISH`, `FRENCH`, and `JAPANESE` we had the formats `MMM d [y]`, `MMMM d`  and `MM d [yy]` (where characters in brackets denote the *start* of the value; for example `[yy]` for `2021` would be `20` *not* `21`). Unsurprisingly, this is where your error generates.

Finally we have `{prior expression} BETWEEN @FROMACCDATE AND @TOACCDATE` which would (had it been successfully converted) have checked to see if the value was between the 2 parameters.

*Presumably* what you are actually trying to see is if a `datetime` value is between 2 `date` values, but ignore the time portion for the `datetime`. To do these you need to use `>=` and `<` date boundaries. For the above, for example, that would be:

```sql
EZ.ACDT >= @FROMACCDATE AND EX.ACDT < DATEADD(DAY,1,@TOACCDATE)
```

For the `SELECT`, just `CONVERT` your value to a `date`, don't format it. Don't do this in the `WHERE` though, as it has performance implications

---

After applying all these changes, this is what you get:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RPT_CAS300_REPORT] (
    --The below variables are used as parameters to search in Report Builder.  The date variables are range dates
    @DIVISION nvarchar(50),
    @FROMACCDATE date,
    @TOACCDATE date,
    @FROMTRANSDATE date,
    @TOTRANSDATE date,
    @ERRORCODE nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN


    SELECT DISTINCT --Is this really needed?
           EZ.DIVI AS DIVISION,
           EZ.ANBR AS [ACCOUNT NUMBER],
           EZ.SENO AS [SEQ NO],
           EZ.EVEN AS EVENT,
           CONVERT(date,EZ.ACDT) AS [ACCOUNTING DATE],
           CONVERT(date,EZ.TRDT) AS [TRANSACTION DATE],
           EZ.ACTY AS [ACCOUNT TYPE],
           EZ.ITNO AS [ITEM NUMBER],
           MM.ITDS AS STYLE,
           MM.BUAR AS BRAND,
           MM.ITGR AS CLASS,
           EZ.ACQT AS QUANTITY,
           EZ.ACAM AS [RECORDED AMOUNT],
           EZ.AIT1 AS [DIM 1: GL],
           EA.TX40 AS [GL DESCRIPTION],
           EZ.AIT2 AS [DIM 2: COST CENTRE],
           EZ.AIT3 AS [DIM 3: BRAND],
           EZ.AIT4 AS [DIM 4: CHANNEL],
           EZ.AIT5 AS [DIM 5: WAREHOUSE],
           EZ.AIT6 AS [DIM 6: ORDER],
           EZ.AIT7 AS [DIM 7: ACCOUNTING RULE],
           EZ.RGDT AS [END DATE],
           EZ.ERCD AS [ERROR CODE]
    FROM CINACC EZ
         LEFT JOIN MITMAS MM ON MM.CONO = EZ.CONO
                            AND MM.ITNO = EZ.ITNO
                            AND EZ.deleted = 'N'
         LEFT JOIN FCHACC EA ON EA.CONO = EZ.CONO
                            AND EA.AITM = EZ.AIT1
                            AND EA.deleted = 'N'
    WHERE EZ.CONO = '100'
      AND (EZ.DIVI IN (SELECT Value FROM dbo.FnSplit(@DIVISION, ',') )
        OR @DIVISION IS NULL)
      AND (EZ.ERCD IN (SELECT Value FROM dbo.FnSplit(@ERRORCODE, ',') )
        OR @ERRORCODE IS NULL)
      AND EZ.ACDT >= @FROMACCDATE AND EX.ACDT < DATEADD(DAY,1,@TOACCDATE)
      AND EZ.TRDT >= @FROMTRANSDATE AND EX.TRDT < DATEADD(DAY,1,@TOTRANSDATE)
      AND EZ.deleted = 'N';


END;
```

I also change the delimit identify to the T-SQL delimit identify, brackets (`[]`). Don't use literal strings for aliases; it's confusing for new users, and it's the *only* place an object name can be defined with a literal string.

*Late Edit: You may also well want to add `RECOMPILE` to an `OPTION` clause in your query. Your handling of allowing `@DIVISION` and `@ERRORCODE` to be `NULL` and all rows are returned could result in **very** different query plans. This would stop the reuse of inappropriate cached plans.*

Comment: You don't need to convert a datetime/datetime2/datetimeoffset/smalldatetime column to a date for a report.  Just pass the value as it is and format it in SSRS as needed.

Comment: @Jeff yes, you are correct we could just format in SSRS but not the way that the business that I am consulting to wishes to have their statements written and managed.  I suggested the same thing but it was requested to format the dates.

Comment: @PaulKalathas - not sure I understand then.  You are converting to a string - then converting to a datetime to be returned to the client.  If all you want is to remove the time component - there are much better options.  You can cast to a date - then cast that to a datetime: cast(cast(nullif(EZ.ACDT as date) as datetime - or dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, nullif(EZ.ACDT, '')), 0).

Answer (score 1):

The error message is very clear, you have a blank string which can't be converted to datetime because it doesn't correspond to any.

Transform those blank string to nulls and you won't have that problem anymore.

```
CONVERT(datetime, nullif(ltrim(CONVERT(CHAR(8), EZ.ACDT)) = ''), 101) as 'ACCOUNTING DATE', 
CONVERT(datetime, nullif(ltrim(CONVERT(CHAR(8), EZ.TRDT)) = ''), 101) AS'TRANSACTION DATE'
```

Although converting from strings to dates is not recommendable, because a malformed date, or one on a different regional settings than yours, will make your query fail. If you can't help it but have to convert from string to date, then use `try_convert` instead of `convert`, because malformed strings (as your blank strings) will just be returned as nulls.

```
TRY_CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), EZ.ACDT), 101) as 'ACCOUNTING DATE', 
TRY_CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), EZ.TRDT), 101) AS 'TRANSACTION DATE'
```

PD: I've changed char(8) to varchar(10) because, as Larnu said, your result should be getting their years truncated.

Comment: Thanks @Marc Guillot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6220377/marc-guillot this also worked during my testing.